# How come pyplot from Matplotlib doesn't allow you to save an image after you show it?

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I put `pyplot.show()` before I try to save an image, the file doesn't actually contain the image.

At first I thought it was a bug  but then I switched `pyplot.show()` and `pyplot.savefig('foo5.png')` and it worked.

Here is an example code piece.

```
def plot(embeddings, labels):
  assert embeddings.shape[0] >= len(labels), 'More labels than embeddings'
  pyplot.figure(figsize=(20, 20))  # in inches
  for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    x, y = embeddings[i,:]
    pyplot.scatter(x, y)
    pyplot.annotate(label, xy=(x, y), xytext=(5, 2), textcoords='offset points',
                   ha='right', va='bottom')
  pyplot.savefig('foo4.png')
  pyplot.show()
  pyplot.savefig('foo5.png')

books = [bookDictionary[i] for i in range(1, num_points2+1)]
plot(two_d_embeddings, books)
print( os.listdir() )
```

foo4.png is just fine, but foo5.png is blank.

Comment: `show()` clears the canvas. You must first `savefig` and then `show`.

Comment: pylab is not recommended to be used anymore, I edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found out yourself, using `pyplot` you need to save the figure before it is `show`n.

This is in fact only true for non-interactive mode (`ioff`), but that is the default and probably most common use case.

What happens is that once `pyplot.show()` is called, the figure is shown and an event loop is started, taking over the python even loop. Hence any command after `pyplot.show()` is delayed until the figure is closed. This means that `pyplot.savefig()`, which comes after `show` is not executed until the figure is closed. Once the figure is closed, there is no figure to save present inside the pyplot state machine anymore.

You may however save a particular figure, in case that is desired. E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3])
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.show()
fig.savefig("foo5.png")
```

Here, we call the `savefig` method of a particular figure (in this case the only one present) for which we need to obtain a handle (`fig`) to that figure.

Note that in such cases, where you need fine control over how matplotlib works it's always useful to not use pyplot, but rely mostly on the object oriented interface.
Hence,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
fig.savefig("foo5.png")
```

would be the more natural way to save a figure after having shown it.