# Matplotlib pdf Output

Tags: pandas, pdf, matplotlib

Im new to matplotlib and wont to use the graphics in Latex.
There ist a visual output as a graphic but:

Why is there no pdf output?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os #to remove a file
import datetime 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
#######################

Val1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,5,5] # in kWh
Val2 = [159,77,1.716246,2,4,73,128,289,372,347,354,302] #in m³


index = ['Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dez','Jan', 'Feb', 'Mrz']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Val1': Val1,'Val2': Val2}, index=index)



with PdfPages('aas2s.pdf') as pdf:

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
params = {'text.latex.preamble' : [r'\usepackage{siunitx}', r'\usepackage{amsmath}']}
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = 'Liberation'
plt.rcParams.update(params)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12}) 
ax = df[['Val1','Val2']].plot.bar(color=['navy','maroon'])

plt.xlabel('X Achse m')
plt.ylabel('Y Achse Taxi quer ')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False)
plt.title('Franz jagt im komplett verwahrlosten Taxi quer durch Bayern')
plt.show()

pdf.savefig()
plt.close()
```

The error is called: ValueError: No such figure: None

And how do i get a second "Y" axis for the second value?

Comment: what do you want to obtain in the plot?

Comment: I think this line has a problem `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `savefig` should be called *before* `show`. See e.g.

- [Matplotlib (pyplot) savefig outputs blank image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012487/matplotlib-pyplot-savefig-outputs-blank-image)
- [How come pyplot from Matplotlib doesn't allow you to save an image after you show it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178853/how-come-pyplot-from-matplotlib-doesnt-allow-you-to-save-an-image-after-you-sho) (with some more explanation)

Second, you want to produce the plot inside the created figure, not create a new one, hence use

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=...)
df.plot(..., ax=ax)
```

and later call the methods of the axes (object-oriented style).

In total,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
#######################

Val1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,5,5] # in kWh
Val2 = [159,77,1.716246,2,4,73,128,289,372,347,354,302] #in m³


index = ['Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dez','Jan', 'Feb', 'Mrz']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Val1': Val1,'Val2': Val2}, index=index)



with PdfPages('aas2s.pdf') as pdf:

    plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
    params = {'text.latex.preamble' : [r'\usepackage{siunitx}', r'\usepackage{amsmath}']}
    plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
    plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = 'Times New Roman'
    plt.rcParams.update(params)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12}) 
    df[['Val1','Val2']].plot.bar(color=['navy','maroon'], ax=ax)

    ax.set_xlabel('X Achse m')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y Achse Taxi quer ')
    ax.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False)
    ax.set_title('Franz jagt im komplett verwahrlosten Taxi quer durch Bayern')
    pdf.savefig()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

Now if you still need to save the figure after is it being shown, you can do so by specifically using it as argument to `savefig`

```
plt.show()
pdf.savefig(fig)
```